# Wildcard find and replace to match sources in parentheses (Word)

Tags: ms-word

I want to create a wildcard find and replace in Word to match all sources in parentheses like the following:

```
(Meierhoff, 2022, S. 99)
(Bauer, 2002)
(Schlüter/Seghers 1999, p. 50-90)
```

I tried to use this find and replace string to match only parentheses that have a number at the end, but it fails.

```
\([A-Za-z0-9\-;:,.\/^32]{6;60}[0-9]{1;4}\)
```

Can someone help me out here? The goal is to apply strike-through to all those parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = \([!\(]@\)
Replace = ^&
```

and you format the replacement as strikethough.

If you want to process only those ending with numbers, use

```
Find = \([!\(]@[0-9]\)
Replace = ^&
```